# How to do this in MySQL? GROUP BY or JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Event table:

```
id  user    type    creation_date   update_date

1   A       AAA     1111            3333
2   A       BBB     2222            4444
3   A       CCC     3333            5555
4   A       DDD     4444            6666
5   B       AAA     3333            4444
6   B       BBB     4444            5555
7   B       CCC     5555            6666
8   C       AAA     2222            3333
9   C       BBB     1111            7777
10  C       CCC     3333            4444
11  C       DDD     4444            9999
```

The task:

Find all users that have at least one DDD event and the user's latest non-DDD event by creation_date is different than the latest non-DDD event by update_date.

So for the records above:

User A has a DDD event. Good. But the last created non-DDD event and the last updated non-DDD event are the same (event #3). So excluded from the result set.

User B has no DDD events. So excluded from the result set.

User C has a DDD event. And the last created non-DDD event (#10) is different from the last updated non-DDD event (#9). So included in the result set.

Result set:

```
user
C
```

I tried different things, including GROUP BY and EXISTS. But I have trouble sort each group of records.

Any idea?

Comment: This sounds too much like "write this for me."

Comment: I'm sort of stuck at: select e1.user
from Event e1
where exists (
    select *
    from Event e2
    where e1.user=e2.user and e2.type="DDD"
)   
and type <> "DDD"
group by e1.user. The difficult part was the sorting of the groups. I can't seem to figure that out.

Comment: @PolishPrince: The Q provides a decent explanation and a proper test case. That sets it apart from most "please write this for me" questions. And it's a rather tricky case. Totally credible that the OP tried and failed as he reports.

Comment: @scabbage: Please *edit* the query you tried into the question, where it is easier to read. Event if it's not working - such information shouldn't be hidden in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an even better idea:

```
SELECT e.usr
FROM  (SELECT usr FROM event WHERE type = 'DDD') u
JOIN   event e USING (usr)
WHERE  e.type <> 'DDD'
GROUP  BY e.usr
HAVING NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM event e0
   WHERE e0.creation_date = max(e.creation_date) 
   AND   e0.update_date   = max(e.update_date)
   AND   e0.usr = e.usr
   AND   e0.type <> 'DDD'
   )
ORDER  BY 1;
```

That should be as simple and fast as it gets now. If you have the right indexes, this should *fly*.

I use `usr` instead of `user`, because the latter a reserved word in standard SQL.

- In subquery `u`, get all users that have at least one row with `type = 'DDD'`.
- Join this set to the base table, getting all rows of the same user with a different event (`type <> 'DDD`).
- In the `HAVING` clause, exclude cases where there is a row with the latest `creation_date` and the latest `update_date`.
- This query even **works with duplicates** in the base table.

#### First attempt

Slower and not as smart:

```
SELECT e.usr
FROM  (SELECT usr FROM event WHERE type = 'DDD') u
JOIN   event e USING (usr)
WHERE  e.type <> 'DDD'
GROUP  BY e.usr
HAVING (SELECT id FROM event WHERE creation_date = max(e.creation_date) AND usr = e.usr AND type <> 'DDD')
    <> (SELECT id FROM event WHERE update_date   = max(e.update_date  ) AND usr = e.usr AND type <> 'DDD')
ORDER  BY 1
```

- This query assumes there cannot be multiple events at the same time for the same user. Else it's unreliable.

[**-> SQLfiddle** displaying both](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2582/6)

Comment: A couple of questions: 1. What do "GROUP BY 1" and "ORDER BY 1" mean? Does the 1 refer to the first column? 2. The latest `creation_date` will most be different from the latest `update_date`. But I'm looking for when the latest event is different if sorted differently. Does that make sense?

Comment: @scabbage: OK, it's working now. The `1` in `GROUP BY 1` is a positional parameter referring to the position of the item in the SELECT list.

Comment: Why do you want the two sub-queries in the `HAVING` statement to be equal? Shouldn't it be `<>`?

Comment: @scabbage: Right, the operator was backwards, I fixed that. More importantly, I came up with a *completely new and better idea* (IMO). Consider the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still wondering if this can be simplified a little, but you could use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user
FROM   yourtable
WHERE  user NOT IN (
  SELECT user
  FROM   yourtable t1
  WHERE
    EXISTS (
      SELECT   NULL
      FROM     yourtable t2
      WHERE    t2.type!='DDD' AND t1.user=t2.user
      GROUP BY user
      HAVING   max(t2.creation_date)=t1.creation_date
             AND max(t2.update_date)=t1.update_date)
  )
  AND EXISTS (SELECT null
              FROM yourtable t2
              WHERE t2.user=yourtable.user
                    AND type='DDD')
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41da4/1).

Comment: I found something rather simple, or so I think.